# how to pass Jmeter thread count in jenkins using Maven

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I want to configure Jmeter script on jenkins to run for particular thread count. lets say 10 or 20 or 30. i am using maven with Jenkins how can i pass the thread value as parameter so can run the job for diff thread everytime. i am using mvn verify command to run jmeter files.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-demo</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jmeter-demo</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
            <argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jmeter-maven-plugin to run your JMeter tests via Maven is fine, although pom.xml is not the place to define properties like thread count etc. What you are looking for is either [__property](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) or [__P](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) JMeter function.

Comment: You can quite easily define properties in the POM that get fed into the JMeter properties files, specifying thread counts is actually a good idea because it give you lots of flexibility when it comes to tweaking your tests to find out just how much your application can handle.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the wiki:

https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties#6

Specifically:

```
+---+
<project>
    [...]
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.10.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jmeter</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <propertiesGlobal>
                                    <threads>10</threads>
                                    <testIterations>5</testIterations>
                                </propertiesGlobal>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    [...]
</project>
+---+
```

If you want to be able to modify these properties on the command line you will want to set Maven properties like so:

```
+---+
<properties>
    <threads>10</threads>
    <testIterations>5</testIterations>
</properties>

<project>
    [...]
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.10.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jmeter</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <propertiesGlobal>
                                    <threads>${threads}</threads>
                                    <testIterations>${testIterations}</testIterations>
                                </propertiesGlobal>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    [...]
</project>
+---+
```

Then you will be able to specify them like so:

```
mvn clean install -Dthreads=5 -DtestIterations=15
```